# I have a vue.js eror

Tags: vue.js

./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/userlist.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@vue/composition-api' in 'C:\Users\Emre\Desktop\vueJS\src\components'

import userlist from './components/userlist.vue'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like you need to install the `@vue/composition-api` module in your project.

try running `npm i --save @vue/composition-api`